# Time Complexity question BigO notation. O(n) vs O(n log n)

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

I am just getting into big O notation and Time complexity, and I am running into an issue with O(n) vs O(log n) vs O(n log n)

Specifically I am comparing O(5 log n) to O(n). I know that O(log n) > O(n) > O(n log n). I think I am getting confused on what the n can represent in O(n log n)

For example, O(5 log n) is going to be faster than O(n) since the 5 will not matter at scale.

Am I understanding this correctly?

This is my first time posting on stackoverflow, so I am sorry if anything here is not done correctly.

I am recently getting into this, and I want to make sure I understand. I feel like this is correct, but I am very new to it.

Comment: Why you use `0` (zero) instead of capital `O`?

Answer (score 1):

I found this resource on AustinCommunityCollege website very informative.

Its for very large values of n. This "complexity analysis" attempts to characterize the relationship between the number of data elements and resource usage (time or space) with a simple formula approximation.

Notation is concerned with what happens for very large values of N

https://www.austincc.edu/akochis/COSC2415/bigo.htm

[image: BigO comparison]

Comment: This table is missing over-exponential growth (e.g. `O(2^n)`)

Answer (score 1):

> I am getting confused on what the n can represent in 0(n log n)

It is some relevant "measure" for the input. It could be literally the input, like if the algorithm calculates the factorial of a number . It could be the *number* of values provided to an algorithm, like for a sorting algorithm. It could be the height of a tree, the number of nodes in a graph, the range (max - min) of a set of input values, ...etc, whatever seems a useful indication for the *size* of the input.

> 0(5 log n) is going to be faster than 0(n) since the 5 will not matter at scale.

It is true that the factor of 5 is irrelevant for Big Oh notation. But be careful with statements about "faster". Complexity is about asymptotic behaviour, and so a O(log) algorithm may actually be *slower* than a O() algorithm for a specific range of input sizes. The only thing you can be certain about is that for large enough input sizes (but you don't know *how* large), the first algorithm will be faster.

Answer (score 0):

As you've found correctly, in the big-O notation, constant multipliers don't matter. In `O(5 log n)` the "5" is just a constant factor that can be neglected, and hence this is the same as `O(1 log n)` which is `O(log n)`. So an algorithm using `O(5 log n)` has the same complexity as one having `O(log n)`. But this is much better than one having `O(n log n)`. (This would be the same as `O(5n log n)`, but again, we ignore that 5 here).

Note that this only applies to factors, not all constants: `O(n^2)` is obviously different from `O(n^1)`.